# Change time format from 04:00 to 00:04:00

Tags: php

I currently get duration in this format: `04:00` but I need in this format `00:04:00`.

I am using this code but it's not working correctly.

```
$time = date("h:i:s", strtotime($duration));
echo $time;
```

Comment: Just add `'00:'.$duration;`

Comment: @mayur Can you please tell that 04 is hour or minute.

Comment: thanks sectus  04 is minit

Comment: No current answer is pointing to the **real**  problem! What you do now is just a *sneaky workaround* and not really nice! Your problem is how you read in your time in which format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this,

```
$duration = "00:"."04:00";
```

Comment: I love how you're concatenating two strings together. Why not `$duration = "00:04:00";` ?

Comment: i think he receives duration in the format 04:00 so he cant change how he is receiving it - therefore this seems right

Comment: but some duration i get in 00:04:00 that's why i m not concatenating

Comment: @ mayur panchal check like this, $arr =  explode (":" , $duration);
 if(sizeof($arr)<3) do concatenation else simply pass your duation

Comment: Thank you so much Ayyanar G you save my time.

Comment: No need to explode and do that much. I hope  substr_count can do it in easy manner with single line and that is much better option

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

(Your problem is in which format you read in your time, so [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php))

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("i:s", "04:00");
echo $date->format('H:i:s');
```

Output:

```
00:04:00
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `strtotime($duration)`; It doesn't know exactly what format that's in, and can't get a valid date from it. (This is why you're getting unexpected results from the `date` function.

If you want to just simply add `00:` before `$duration`, you can do it like so:

```
$duration = '04:00';

$duration = '00:' . $duration;
```

You then would be able to pass this to the `strtotime` function, and would likely get better results.